# Replicating output of excel COUNTIFs in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

[image]

I have dataset with the following column - Source, Sink, StartDate, EndDate, Class, MW, ClearingPrice. I am trying to create a column (Path_Repeat) that takes value 1 if the a particular Source-Sink combinations reverse exists in the dataset for the same StartDate and EndDate.

I was able to do this in excel by using a =COUNTIFS(A:A,B2,B:B,A2,C:C,C2,D:D,D2,E:E,E2). I wondering if there is a way of doing this in pandas that is faster than excel.

Comment: Don't think your formula is right. 1. You have two `COUNTIFS`. 2. Your formula for source-sink B-A would be true, if a following combination existed: source:C, sink:B and source:A,sink:D, but there's no reverse path

Comment: Apologies, I made an error while copying my formula. I used only 1 COUNTIFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Source": ["A", "B", "A", "B"],
        "Sink": ["B", "A", "C", "A"],
        "StartDate": ["1/1/2010", "1/1/2010", "1/1/2010", "2/1/2010"],
        "EndDate": ["31/1/2010", "31/1/2010", "31/1/2010", "31/1/2010"],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Create a new column for comparison
df["key"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["Source"] + x["Sink"], axis=1)
df["key"] = df["key"].apply(lambda x: "".join(sorted(x)))

# Search for duplicates
df.loc[
    df.duplicated(subset=["StartDate", "EndDate", "key"], keep=False), "Path_Repeat"
] = 1

# Cleanup
df = df.fillna(0).astype({"Path_Repeat": int})
```

```py
  Source Sink StartDate    EndDate key  Path_Repeat
0      A    B  1/1/2010  31/1/2010  AB            1
1      B    A  1/1/2010  31/1/2010  AB            1
2      A    C  1/1/2010  31/1/2010  AC            0
3      B    A  2/1/2010  31/1/2010  AB            0
```